# Bootstrap - new line on small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and I have this line:

```
<p>{{ user.email }} <span class="pull-right">{{ user.role }}</span></p>
```

How can I make it so that the span goes on a new line if the device size is "xs"?

Comment: have you tried media queries?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to use a custom class for this as the `pull-right` class will interfere since it's set to `!important` by default.

Or you can override it by using `!important` on another class.

See working examples in Snippet at Full Page.

```css
body, html {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.new-class {
  float: right;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .new-class {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .newer-class {
    display: block;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>email <span class="new-class">role</span>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <p>email <span class="newer-class pull-right">role</span>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with an break element, that is only active on xs-devices...

```
<p>{{ user.email }} <br class="d-xs-inline d-sm-none" /> <span class="pull-right">{{ user.role }}</span></p>
```